# EditText remove focus if setText()

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` that as an `textChangedListener`

When I use `myEditText.setText("")` two things happen:

1. The keyboard pops up
2. The `texChangedListener` (TextWatcher) is fired.

I want to know if there is a way of removing any related events when we use `setText()`

The first problem I've solved with

```
if (getWindow() != null) {
       getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
}
```

just before `myEditText.setText("")` but I still think that should be a way of disabling the events from firing in specific situations.

Any idea for the 2 point or how I should handle this events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the editText change listener to null, then set its text to empty string, and finally  set the change listener again.

Answer (score 0):

```
myEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
myEditText.setText("");
myEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
```